# Magento 2 - Set collection limit in a Model

Tags: magento, collections, magento2

I created a model file which I would like a method inside me to return products with a limit.

Below my model:

```
    <?php

namespace Test\Ice\Model;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

/**
 * System configuration values
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_config;

/**
 * Store manager interface
 *
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * Product interface
 *
 */
protected $_product;

/**
 * Initialize
 *
 * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
 * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
 * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection, 
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, 
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_product = $collection;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProducts() {

    $limit = 10;

    return $this->_product->getSelect()->limit($limit);

}
```

}

The problem is that it does not make the limit, but always returns all products in the collection.
Where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Enzo, do echo $this->_product->getSelect(); is printing the query correctly ?

Comment: This is result of query: SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`

Comment: try using $this->_product->getCollection()->setPageSize(20)->setCurPage(1);

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::getCollection() in ...

Comment: Sorry i overlooked your line \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection try  $this->_product->setPageSize(20)->setCurPage(1); as this is already a collection object

Comment: Return all products without limits

Comment: Maybe your collection is loaded already. What does `Zend_Debug::dump($this->_product->isLoaded());` says ?

Answer (score 4):

Use 
`$this->_product->getCollection()->setPageSize(10)->setCurPag‌​e(1);`

Comment: I am also using your way in my custom web API, but then it limits the the list to a single product. Can you please advice?

Comment: May the filters in your collection return just a single result.

Comment: Without pagination, full result set is returned, but when i add pagination wtih setCurrPage(1) and setPageSize(10), it returns single record.